# White and Rodgers programable thermostat

Tags: thermostat

Every Monday morning, 12:00 a.m. my heat goes on to 70*.  It is not programmed to go on.  It does this automatically. It stays at 70* until it is programmed to go down and runs properly until the next Monday incident.  I can't find the problem.  Help.

Comment: It would be very helpful to include the specific model number. In the meantime, consider programming in a "reset" on Monday at 12:30 am to reset it to your desired temperature as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The specifics vary between brands & models, but it is typical for a programmable thermostat to have 4 setpoints per day (time & temperature) with the setpoints either for weekend (Saturday & Sunday the same) and weekday (Monday through Friday) or each individual day of the week. Some thermostats give both options.

Since this happens specifically Monday 12:00am, it sounds like when the thermostat was programmed that the first Monday setpoint was missed. Note that many computerized systems (programmable thermostats being a simple example) actually start with Monday - see [ISO week day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) for more details. This means that "first setpoint on Monday" may actually be "very first setpoint in the thermostat".

In any case, the solution is to step through the programming routine for every setting of every day. In a worst case scenario (bug in the thermostat firmware that makes it always reset at 12:00 Monday with no option to change the temperature - extremely unlikely), set the desired temperature for 12:15am Monday (most thermostats I have seen use a 15-minute increment) and you will essentially solve the problem.